# How can I convert a cell array to numerical array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, cell, nan

I have read some data from an Excel file in Matlab. A cell array has been generated as follow:

```
x={'11', 'NaN', 'NaN', '13', 24}
```

I want to convert cell array to a numeric matrix (for other required calculations) and convert 'NaN' elements to zero in my numeric matrix. How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str2double` to convert strings to numeric values:

```
x={'11', 'NaN', 'NaN', '13', '24'};
nx = str2double(x);
```

Once you have numeric values, you can substitute the `nan`s with zeros:

```
nx(isnan(nx))=0
```

Comment: @Yaser, this won't work if the input is as in the question - the last value (24) is a number, not a string. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41530933/2627163) to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave in the question there is a mixed content (strings and numbers), so it takes 2 steps:

```
x = {'11', 'NaN', 'NaN', '13', 24}; % last value is a number
isch = cellfun(@isstr,x); % find all strings
numx(isch) = str2double(x(isch)); % convert the strings to numbers, and place the correcly
numx(~isch) = cell2mat(x(~isch)); % extract the numbers and place the correcly
```

Then you can replace all `NaN`s with zeros:

```
numx(isnan(numx)) = 0;
```

the result:

```
numx =

    11     0     0    13    24
```